# Circular structure when getting Google OAuth2 callback on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, sails.js, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

I'm using Node v4.4.0, npm 2.14.20 and sails 0.10.5. I've created simple application with Google OAuth2 (all I have is Auth controller with User model and configured passport in config/passport.js) and it's working fine when run locally but fails when deployed on Heroku. From logs I suspect there's a problem creating new session after user is already authenticated by Google. I've appended a log below, did anybody experience similar problem before?

```
016-03-16T18:54:01.206409+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/login" host=porocila-treningov.herokuapp.com request_id=2650d7a4-0047-45b6-bd64-fbe122902c9b fwd="92.53.152.70" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=33ms status=200 bytes=1382
2016-03-16T18:54:33.179402+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/auth/google" host=porocila-treningov.herokuapp.com request_id=e91d0c55-cf6a-4aef-b994-96c3b92bcf9a fwd="92.53.152.70" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=9ms status=302 bytes=528
2016-03-16T18:54:35.675271+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session/memory.js:72
2016-03-16T18:54:35.675281+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.sessions[sid] = JSON.stringify(sess);
2016-03-16T18:54:35.675282+00:00 app[web.1]:                               ^
2016-03-16T18:54:35.675283+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-03-16T18:54:35.675284+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.stringify (native)
2016-03-16T18:54:35.675284+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
2016-03-16T18:54:35.675286+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:390:13)
2016-03-16T18:54:35.675285+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session/memory.js:72:31
2016-03-16T18:54:35.675286+00:00 app[web.1]:     at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
2016-03-16T18:54:35.696055+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-03-16T18:54:35.706858+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v4.4.0
2016-03-16T18:54:35.707355+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v2.14.20
------------SOME MORE CRASH INFO, HOW TO SUBMIT BUG, HOW TO FIND AUTHOR ETC-----------
2016-03-16T18:54:35.669056+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/auth/google/callback?code=4/-OF3ImicWoSJkNfnoO60C7MNFVUtAj7YG2PXRUQkIUs" host=porocila-treningov.herokuapp.com request_id=a5578684-269c-44a0-abdc-2808517a4ea7 fwd="92.53.152.70" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=355ms status=302 bytes=409
2016-03-16T18:54:36.506369+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-03-16T18:54:36.518470+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2016-03-16T18:54:37.792637+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/login" host=porocila-treningov.herokuapp.com request_id=1ab7a2b5-80fb-48b5-993d-ac0f213c996a fwd="92.53.152.70" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: check if sess is not a circular object!

Answer (score 0):

Circular structure error happens when you any how assign some object to some key for that object.
for example...

```
var obj={
  'x':1,
  'y':false
};
obj.z=obj;//or anyhow this happens by mistake
```

see the screenshot!!!
[image]

so this is ow circular object is formed....and while stringifying such objects cause exception.

Comment: Yes, I know what the problem is, I just don't know how to solve it. Why would session be circular when deployed on Heroku but not when run locally?

Comment: do console.log(sess) before JSON.stringify(sess) on local and as well as sess to figure out the difference!that may help